# How to upload multiple files and combine them in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large size exe file (> 100 MB) which I need to upload to S3. Now since I have a reliable network, I want to make this process faster by dividing the file into chunks and then uploading these chunks in parallel. But I don't know how to merge these chunks back together to get the original exe?

Although python provides a way to upload a file into chunks but those chunks are uploaded serially. Is there any way to upload these chunks in parallel and then merge them back together?

Comment: I guess the limiting factor here is your upload speed from your internet connection. Let's say your upload is 20Mbit. How, exactly, would sending 2x10Mbit be faster than 1x20Mbit? Also S3 does not provide any computing power. You can spin up an EC2 instance to receive the traffic and push it to S3 though.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for 7zip like features but with python Api

Comment: Agree with Bjorn .... Splitting file won't increase the speed. Unless you have a gigabit speed n/w in which case the time and resources spent in splitting and uploading might be more significant than uploading as a whole.

Comment: Agree with @Bjorn. Your best bet is to split the files then spin up a EC2 then upload them in parallel (there are many tools to do that). Then you merge them remotely and finally push to S3. Since you should spin up a EC2 in the same AZ as the S3, the speed between that EC2 instance and S3 will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 already has support for this.

It's called a multipart upload: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

Use a client (for example s3cmd http://s3tools.org/kb/item13.htm) that knows how to do this or use do it yourself through the SDK and your favorite language.